# How to filter by parent/child relationship instead alphabetically on aldeed:tabular?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Right now the index of tabular looks like this:

[image: tabular_1]

See how it renders rows alphabetically but what I want to do is render rows by parent/child relationships.

I'm trying to structure the tabular index page like this:

[image: tabular_2]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Please actually read the preceding link and make sure that the code you post **in your question** is **minimal** (only bare minimum of code necessary to reproduce), **complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **verifiable** (we can reproduce the issue using only the code in your question). Without a proper MCVE **in your question**, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I dont have code because I don't know where to start, I just want to know if there are people that figured out a way to customize tabular in some way.